# Constructing invertible sheaves out of actions of finite groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a quasiprojective algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$ with structure sheaf $\mathcal{O}_X$ and let $G$ be a finite group which acts freely on $X$.  The quotient $Y = X/G$ is thus a quasiprojective variety in a canonical way; let $\mathcal{O}_Y$ be its structure sheaf.  Assume that $c : G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ is a homomorphism.  Define a sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $Y$ as follows.  Let $\pi : X \rightarrow Y$ be the projection map.  Consider an open set $U \subset Y$.  Let $V = \pi^{-1}(U)$.  The group $G$ acts in a natural way on $V$, and we get an action of $G$ on $\mathcal{O}_X(V)$ via the formula

$$g \cdot \phi(x) = \phi(g^{-1} \cdot x) \cdot c(g) \quad \quad (g \in G, \phi \in \mathcal{O}_X(V), x \in V).$$

Define $\mathcal{F}(U)$ to be the invariants $(\mathcal{O}_X(V))^G$ of this action.

I'm pretty sure that $\mathcal{F}$ is an invertible sheaf (ie a line bundle).  If we were working analytically rather than algebraically, then this would basically be obvious; however, since things are only quasiprojective we don't have GAGA available, and I can't figure out how to deal with Zariski open sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is classical, can be found in Mumford: Abelian varieties, II.7 (i think) group actions on varieties (however without the twist, you mention, but i think it is no poblem), and the main reason (again without the twist) is that $\pi^{*}\mathcal{F}\cong \mathcal{O}_{X}$. You can use this to conclude...

Comment: Without the twist, it's entirely trivial!  Indeed, without the twist, $\mathcal{F}$ is just $\mathcal{O}_Y$...

Comment: Actually, I just looked there, and Proposition 3 of that section of Mumford has the result I wanted (twist and all).  Thanks!

Comment: yes it is trivial without the twist, but i forgot to say that $\mathcal{F}$ can be any quasi-coherent $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ module...

Comment: i mean $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ can be substituted by any coherent $\mathcal{O}_{X}$ module...
